# Firebug break on error functionality

Tags: firebug

I was wondering when a error message pops up in Firebug, what does that **disable** mean? I tried to search in [Firebug Docs](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) but no luck. Can someone please advise? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click ***Disable***, it stops the code from breaking at that point during future runs.
It also marks the line with a breakpoint and disables it.

[image]

Note: Extra breakpoint added for reference.